# STM32 and Elegoo supply voltage

Tags: arduino, stm32, adc

I wrote code using an STM32F407 to read the voltage of a potentiometer on the input pin of the ADC.

[image]

This is the circuit:

[image]

I tried taking the power directly from the STM32 and then, as in the photo above, I tried taking the power from the Elegoo board. In the case of the STM32 I can read the correct values, but in the case of the Elegoo I get this:

[image]

Why it doesn't work with the Elegoo's Vcc? Does the Elegoo have some problems with the power pins?

It is definitely a hardware problem, because the code is the same, but in the case of the STM32 it works.

Comment: Do the boards share ground connection, or are they separately powered from separate sources that are unrelated and floating in respect to each other? How are they powered? Show the big picture, these details on the photo are not enough.

Comment: @Justme Reading your reply, I noticed that I did not connect GND of the two boards (STM32 and Elegoo) together. I connected them together and now everything works. Thank you! However, can you tell me specifically why it was not working with the two GNDs disconnected from each other? If GND indicates a fixed 0V potential ... then there should be no need to connect the GNDs of two different circuits (i.e. in this case STM32 and Elegoo) together :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no common ground potential between boards.

You can define any point as 0V or ground level to which everything else is referenced. However, as an analogy, if you live in a valley and your friend lives on top of a hill, you both may be same height, but your heads will be at different level compared to sea level which is absolute, so you and your friend share a different ground level reference in absolute numbers.

So a board cannot measure or work with anything that is not referenced to ground of that board.

Same thing if you have two 9V batteries. They both have 9V over their terminals and you can name the negative terminals as 0V or ground or whatever, but they are completely unrelated to each other, until you connect a wire between them.

If you try to measure anything with a multimeter between the two otherwise unconnected batteries, you will get nothing, no voltage and no current, no resistance, nothing.

So in order to measure the voltage output of a potentiometer, the potentiometer and the measuring board must have the same ground, i.e. 0V reference, and the supply going into the potentiometer must be referenced to board and potentiometer ground.